# Kestrel stuck with MVC app

Tags: asp.net, mono, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

So, my story is:

I took clean VM with Debian8x64 OS, installed DNVM according to this instructions: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html, installed mono according to this: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Then I took samples from here: https://github.com/aspnet/home, launched it, and all seems fine.

After this I created very simple MVC application in Visual Studio 2015 with ASP.NET 5 project template and copied this code on Debian VM. It run fine too, but when I try call it from browser it stuck, kestrel not responding. Besides, Hello world MVC App stuck also after that.

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPD: Output with DNX_TRACE**

```
Information: [Bootstrapper] Runtime Framework: DNX,Version=v4.5.1
Information: [ApplicationHostContext] Using Lock File Target: DNX,Version=v4.5.1/debian.8-x64
Information: [DefaultHost]: Project path: /home/brewer/Documents/samples/home/samples/1.0.0-rc1-update1/HelloMvc
Information: [DefaultHost]: Project root: /home/brewer/Documents/samples/home/samples/1.0.0-rc1-update1/HelloMvc
Information: [DefaultHost]: Project configuration: Debug
Information: [DefaultHost]: Packages path: /root/.dnx/packages
Information: [Breadcrumbs] Breadcrumbs for servicing will not be written because the breadcrumbs folder () does not exist.
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel in 4ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Http, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Http, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Physical, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.FileProviders.Physical, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=HelloMvc
Warning: [ApplicationHostContext] Lock File Target is Runtime-agnostic! This is generally not good.
Information: [ApplicationHostContext] Using Lock File Target: DNX,Version=v4.5.1/
Information: [LibraryExporter]: ExportProject(HelloMvc, , DNX,Version=v4.5.1, Debug)
Warning: [ApplicationHostContext] Lock File Target is Runtime-agnostic! This is generally not good.
Information: [ApplicationHostContext] Using Lock File Target: DNX,Version=v4.5.1/
Information: [LibraryExporter]: GetProjectReference(Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp.RoslynProjectCompiler, HelloMvc, DNX,Version=v4.5.1, )
Information: [LibraryExporter]: Resolving references for 'HelloMvc' 
Information: [LibraryExporter]: Resolved 87 references for 'HelloMvc' in 18ms
Information: [RoslynCompiler]: Compiling 'HelloMvc'
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Information: [RoslynCompiler]: Compiled 'HelloMvc' in 596ms
Information: [CompilationContext]: Generating resources for HelloMvc
Information: [CompilationContext]: Generated resources for HelloMvc in 6ms
Information: [RoslynProjectReference]: Emitting assembly for HelloMvc
Information: [RoslynProjectReference]: Emitted HelloMvc in 1223ms
Information: [ProjectAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=HelloMvc in 2115ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ApiExplorer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ApiExplorer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DataAnnotations, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.DataAnnotations, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Cors, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Cors, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Routing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Routing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.MemoryPool, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.MemoryPool, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Antiforgery, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Html.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Html.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.Internal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Cryptography.Internal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Host, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Host, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Razor, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Razor, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Cors, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Cors, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://*:5004
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a in 0ms
[32minfo[39m[37m: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1][39m
[97m      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5004/  [39m
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed in 0ms
Information: [ApplicationHostContext] Using Lock File Target: DNX,Version=v4.5.1/debian.8-x64
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
[32minfo[39m[37m: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionInvoker[1][39m
[97m      Executing action method MvcSample.Web.HomeController.Index with arguments () - ModelState is Valid'[39m
Information: [LoaderContainer]: Load name=Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime, `      Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60`
Information: [PackageAssemblyLoader]: Loaded name=Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 in 0ms
```

Comment: Can you please set the environment variable `DNX_TRACE` to `1` and rerun the server. Share the output.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I need some rest for my eyes. I've updated my question with the output.

Comment: There doesn't seem to anything obviously wrong in that log... Can you please share more details about what you're doing? (1) What url do you access? (2) How do you know kestrel is stuck? (3) Can you share the app that you are running? (4) What DNX version do you use?

Comment: (1) http://localhost:5004  (2) browser is hanging with responce and as you can see in log there is no information about kestrel responce (3) I trying to launch "HelloWorld" MVC App from asp.net 5 samples (4) latest dnx version, 1.0.0-rc1-upgrade1

Comment: In your Startup.cs where you have `loggerFactory.AddConsole();`, can you change that to `loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Trace);`?

Comment: Hm... I added LogLevel.Trace to loggerFactory.AddConsole method and got error "Log level does not contain a definition for Trace". I tried LogLevel.Verbose and all built fine. As I see in LogLevel.cs history Verbose has been renamed to Trace  on Dec 7th. This means, that I have old sources. How this could happen if I've made "dnu restore" command before "dnx web"? Is this caching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried use CoreCLR instead Mono and all working perfectly. Mono is suspect:)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this in Centos 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 and the following gets it working.

Add the following environment variable at the shell (or in your .bashrc file)

`export MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU=2000`

then run

`dnx web`